# Number of surjective functions with given property

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, order-theory

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 2$ and $M = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. Show that there are more than $2^n$ surjective functions $f : \mathcal{P}(M) \rightarrow \{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$ such that $f(A) \leq f(B)$ for all $A \subseteq B \subseteq M$.

($\mathcal{P}(M)$ is the power set of $M$)

My first thought was representing each subset as a bitset of length $n$, then defining a function for each bitset $A$, for example $f_A(B) = \text{popcount(A XOR B)}$, and playing around with other operations such as sum/difference $\pmod{2^n}$. Then, I would find another unrelated function which satisfies the property (for example, the maximum function or the cardinality function) and state that there would be at least $2^n + 1$ functions. The problem is that the bitwise functions have some edge cases that fail to satisfy the property.

Then, I tried to actually compute the number of functions but I don't know how to make sure the property holds while calculating. I suppose the final formula will probably involve ordered Bell numbers due to inclusion being a partial ordering.

Comment: Just making your function a sum of terms will ensure $f(A)\leq f(B)$ for all $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: @Karl $f_S$ is not surjective!

Comment: @Michael the function is bounded by $0$ and $n$.

Comment: @Stevineon : True. I guess you can take a min with $n$, say $f(A) = \min\{\sum_{i\in A} v_i, n\}$ for some nonnegative integers $v_i$.

Comment: @Michael this is only one function, how do I get to $2^n$?

Comment: Distinct values $(v_1, ..., v_n)$ give you different functions. I assume $v_i\in\{0, ..., n\}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following stronger result holds:

> There are at least $n!$ surjective functions $f:\mathcal{P}(M)\to
> \{0,1,\dots, n\}$ such that $f(A)\leq f(B)$ for $A\subseteq B$.

**Proof:**
For a fixed permutation $\sigma:M\to M$ define a function $f_{\sigma}:\mathcal{P}(M)\to \{0,\dots, n\}$ as follows:

- Set $f_\sigma(\emptyset)=0$
- For singletons $\{i\}$ set $f_\sigma(\{i\})=\sigma(i)$
- For any $S\subseteq M$ with $|S|\geq 2$ set
  $$f_\sigma(S) = \min\left(\sum_{s\in S}\sigma(s), n\right)$$

It's easy to verify that $f_\sigma$ is surjective, $f_\sigma(A)\leq f_\sigma(B)$ when $A\subseteq B$ and that two different permutations $\sigma$, $\sigma'$ give rise to two different functions $f_\sigma$ and $f_{\sigma'}$. This procedure generates at least $n!$ such surjective functions.

For $n\geq 4$ this result is stronger than what you want to prove. One could work out the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$ by hand. For the case $n=3$ notice that the above already gives you $3!=6$ functions so it's easier if you try to expand on that set by trying to find $3$ more different functions (notice that functions assigning the same value to two or more singletons are guaranteed to be different from the already constructed ones).